# Check for the existence of more than one value in a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say I have a simple table

```
cust    location
001     USA
001     India
002     Ranchacucamunga
002     Ala-Lemu
```

I want to find anyone that has been to both USA and India.

I'm thinking something like:

```
SELECT 
CASE location
WHEN location is both USA and India 
THEN foo
ELSE bar
END
```

I don't know how to do the `WHEN` part. And I don't know where to put the `GROUP BY`!

In my experience, MySQL just wants to return rows. How can I get MySQL to check for the existence of more than one value in a field?

*EDIT*

both solutions are equally good I just accepted the earlier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a where statement to specify your locations

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE location IN ('USA', 'India')
```

If you want customers that have been to both do this

```
SELECT cust, group_concat(location)
FROM table
WHERE location IN ('USA', 'India')
GROUP BY cust
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

For customers that have been to usa and india at a minimum of one time you can do this

```
SELECT cust, GROUP_CONCAT(location) as locations, sum(location = 'USA') as num_loc, sum(location = 'India') as num_loc1
FROM table
WHERE location IN ('USA', 'India')
GROUP BY cust
HAVING count(*) > 1 AND num_loc > 0 AND num_loc1 > 0
```

note you can change the `> 0` to be any number of times. if you want customers that have visited usa twice and india twice just change
`HAVING count(*) > 1 AND num_loc > 0 AND num_loc1 > 0` to `HAVING count(*) > 1 AND num_loc > 1 AND num_loc1 > 1`

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f88c/5)

Comment: Be leery of the arbitrary location value in `SELECT *` with the group by.

Comment: This is what bugs me about MySQL -- every question you ask it has to be framed around the idea of counting returned rows.

Comment: Might want to keep the `WHERE location in (...) ` clause to give the optimizer more info when determining the execution plan, but your milage may vary.

Comment: what do I do if I don't want `num_loc` and `num_loc1` in the final result? I assume I have to do either a join or a subquery? I hate how, in the course of finding if 2 values exist in a few records, I am forced to create new fields that I don't want. MySQL is so circuitous. This would take one line in a language like R.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck you can use group_concat if you want both of those values. [see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f88c/5)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: I said *don't* want! :)

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck well assuming you are using this query with another programming language to get some desired result, you can just ignore those fields.. if its just because you want to you could put it in a subquery. but thats just preference. on the flip side it may be nice to show how many times someone visited a particular country

Comment: @JohnRuddell: in your opinion, do you think there is fundamentally something weird about having to derive new variables, just to check for existence? I personally do, and this is why I think MySQL is a horrible language.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I agree that there is something weird about that. I personally prefer psql. However MySQL is intended to be like that, so thats how I use it (generally not in all cases though) :) I tried to do it without any subqueries to enhance the speed of the query but it is a little strange

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use INTERSECT for this, but as INTERSECT is not available in MySQL you must use equivalent JOIN's instead, or use counting as has already been suggested:

```
select a.cust from 
( select cust from simple_table t1 where t1.location = 'USA') a
inner join
( select cust from simple_table t2 where t2.location = 'India' ) b on a.cust = b.cust
```

You can write that better as follows (which is more readable to my eyes):

```
select 
  cust 
from 
  simple_table t1 
inner join
  simple_table t2 using (cust)
where 
  t1.location = 'USA' and t2.location = 'India';
```